# check if Special characters is Chinese or English

Tags: java, android

Now my app needs to check the input. I can recognize whether the input is Chinese, English or a number, but there are also special characters in Chinese and English. How to check this?

there is different between Special characters in Chinese mode  and English mode,like this：

```
chineseMode: ， 。
EnglishMode：, .
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: you mean special chacters in chinese ??

Comment: do u want to replace those ?

Comment: You can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541371/php-how-do-i-detect-if-an-input-string-is-arabic). Its about arabic, but i guess you can alter it for Chinese or any other language.

Comment: @Shiv yes in special Chacters there is different between Chin and Engl

Comment: @AndroidKiller no,just to check it out

Comment: @Alankar thank you but isn't what i want ,i can check the language

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help you.you can try like this using regex and also you can add other special characters here.

```
boolean result = yourString.contains("[-+.^:,]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check special characters:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[&%$#@!()*^]"); //<---- you can add more characters to check here 
    Matcher m = p.matcher(myEditText2);
    if (m.find()) {
        editText.setError("you can not enter special Character");
        return false;
    }
```

import these packages:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```